# how to add dynamic data into grid in gwt with number of rows based on database records and columns 5

Tags: gwt

Grid g=new Grid(arg0.size(),5);

```
                    g.setBorderWidth(5);
                    g.setTitle("users data");
                    g.setVisible(true);
                    g.setCellSpacing(3);
                    g.setCellPadding(2);
                    g.setText(0,0, "empid");
                    g.setText(0,1, "first name");
                    g.setText(0,2, "last name");
                    g.setText(0,3, "gender");
                    g.setText(0,4, "studies");


                  System.err.println("list = "+arg0);

                  for(int i=0;i<arg0.size();i++)
                  {
                      User data=  (User) arg0.get(i);

                 for(int row=1;row<arg0.size();row++)
                 {
                      for(int col=0;col<5;col++)
                      {

                          g.setText(row, col,String.valueOf(data.getEmpid()));
                          g.setText(row, col,data.getFirstname());
                          g.setText(row, col, data.getLastname());
                          g.setText(row, col,data.getGender());
                          g.setText(row, col, data.getStudies());
                      }  
                      }

                  }



                  RootPanel.get().clear();
                  RootPanel.get().add(g);
```

arg0 is list of User pojo. in every column the last field is only adding but we have to add appropriate data into each column. mostly i did wrong in for loop please correct me and give response

Comment: Why don't you use a DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

To add the data correctly, have the for-loop like this:

```
// make the grid the size of the userlist + 1 for the header line
Grid g = new Grid(arg0.size() + 1, 5);

// rest of the Grid-definition
;

// per user in the user-list, add one row
for(int i=0;i<arg0.size();i++){
     // retrieve the current user
     User data=  (User) arg0.get(i);

     // add the data of that user in the correct column
     // concerning the row: add in currentRow+1 to compensate for header row
     g.setText(i+1, 0,String.valueOf(data.getEmpid()));
     g.setText(i+1, 1,data.getFirstname());
     g.setText(i+1, 2, data.getLastname());
     g.setText(i+1, 3,data.getGender());
     g.setText(i+1, 4, data.getStudies());


 }
```

However, another way would be using a CellTable. It is much more flexible than your Grid, you can easily add/remove rows, and it's much easier to e.g. change the order of the columns, should that be necessary some time in the future. Additionally, it provides interfaces for column sorting should that be necessary. If you're interested in seeing a CellTable example, let me know so that I can update this post.